# How WinRT events are interoperate with .NET

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, system.reactive, windows-runtime

In the latest video by Rx team [*Bart De Smet: Rx Update - .NET 4.5, Async, WinRT*](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-Rx-Updat-NET-45-Async-WinRT) I saw that WinRT events exposed to .NET by some really strange metadata, more preciesly - `add_`/`remove_` pair methods signature:

```
EventRegistrationToken add_MyEvent(EventHandler<MyEventArgs> handler) { … }
void remove_MyEvent(EventRegistrationToken registrationToken) { … }
```

It looks really great, allowing unsubscribing from event by "disposing" the registration token (Rx does the same kind of thing, returning `IDisposable` instance from `Subscribe()` method). So it's became possible to easily unsubscribe lamba-expressions from events, but...

So how does C# allows for working with this kind of events? In .NET it's possible to subscribe an method (static and instance) with one instance on delegate and unsubscribe with completely another delegate instance pointed to the same method. So if I using an WinRT event and just do unsubscribing of some delegate type instance in C#... where did compiler get the correct `EventRegistrationToken`? How all this magic works?

**-- update --**

Actually `EventRegistrationToken` doesn't allows to unsubscribe simply by calling some kind of `Dispose()` method, that is really sadly:

```
public struct EventRegistrationToken
{
    internal ulong Value { get; }
    internal EventRegistrationToken(ulong value)
    public static bool operator ==(EventRegistrationToken left, EventRegistrationToken right)
    public static bool operator !=(EventRegistrationToken left, EventRegistrationToken right)
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    public override int GetHashCode()
}
```

**-- update2 --**

WinRT interoperability actually uses *global* table of registration tokens when subscribing WinRT events with managed objets. For example, interop code for removing handlers looks like this:

```
internal static void RemoveEventHandler<T>(Action<EventRegistrationToken> removeMethod, T handler)
{
  object target = removeMethod.Target;
  var eventRegistrationTokenTable = WindowsRuntimeMarshal.ManagedEventRegistrationImpl.GetEventRegistrationTokenTable(target, removeMethod);
  EventRegistrationToken obj2;
  lock (eventRegistrationTokenTable)
  {
    List<EventRegistrationToken> list;
    if (!eventRegistrationTokenTable.TryGetValue(handler, out list)) return;
    if (list == null || list.Count == 0) return;
    int index = list.Count - 1;
    obj2 = list[index];
    list.RemoveAt(index);
  }
  removeMethod(obj2);
}
```

That is really sadly.

Comment: Note that everything you've described is an implementation detail and may be changed at any time.  You should NEVER rely on any behavior you reverse engineer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you add or remove a delegate to an WinRT event, like this:

```
this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

this.Loaded -= MainPage_Loaded;
```

It looks just like you were working with normal .Net events. But this code actually compiles to something like this (Reflector seems to have some trouble decompiling WinRT code, but I think this is what the code actually does):

```
WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler<RoutedEventHandler>(
    new Func<RoutedEventHandler, EventRegistrationToken>(this.add_Loaded),
    new Action<EventRegistrationToken>(remove_Loaded),
    new RoutedEventHandler(this.MainPage_Loaded));

WindowsRuntimeMarshal.RemoveEventHandler<RoutedEventHandler>(
    new Action<EventRegistrationToken>(this.remove_Loaded),
    new RoutedEventHandler(this.MainPage_Loaded));
```

This code won't actually compile, because you can't access the `add_` and `remove_` methods from C#. But you can that in IL, and that's exactly what the compiler does.

It looks like [`WindosRuntimeMarshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.windowsruntimemarshal%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) keeps all those `EventRegistrationToken`s and uses them to unsubscribe when necessary.

Comment: Oh no, seems it's really keep the **global table** of all the subscribes from managed objects...

Comment: MSDN has a pretty good article about this at [Custom events and event accessors in Windows Runtime Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972883.aspx).  @svick, you weren't that far off

Answer (score 9):

Would you accept "there are some amazingly clever people working on the C# language projection" as an answer?

More seriously, what you've discovered is the low level ABI (binary) implementation of the event pattern, the C# language projection knows this pattern and knows how to expose it as C# events.  There are classes inside the CLR that implement this mapping.

Comment: Sounds more like the C# WinRT team is putting lipstick on the pig :)

Comment: Why lipstick on a pig?  This is exactly how language projections work.  The windows runtime has an eventing pattern (and an async pattern and a collections pattern and other patterns).  Every API that exposes events uses the same pattern.  A language projection's job is to take APIs which use that pattern and make them feel natural and familiar to users of that language.  The windows runtime couldn't simply adopt the C# eventing pattern, because of two reasons: the windows runtime has to be language agnostic and the runtime uses reference counting for lifetime management.

Comment: It unfortunately is also correct.  The low level projection for events is straightforward - there's an event add and an event remove method, the add takes a delegate and returns a token, the remove takes the token.  When the event is fired, the delegate is called.  The CLR maps this low level mechanism into a CLR compatible version.    The actual names of the classes used are an implementation detail and are subject to change from one build to another.  JavaScript has a totally different implementation of the same mechanism as does C++.  And all the implementations are subject to change.