# Unusual code by the decompiler

Tags: c#

I tried to decompile a .cs file through telerik decompiler and it changed an event handler's code into an unusual.

```
private void Start_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler<EventHandler<Object>>(new Func<EventHandler<Object>, EventRegistrationToken>(dispatcherTimer.add_Tick), new Action<EventRegistrationToken>(dispatcherTimer.remove_Tick), new EventHandler<Object>(this.timer_Tick));
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
}
```

I don't know how to change it to normal. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: By typing in the correct code?  The decompiler is only going to give you what it sees based on what is in the assembly's IL, and what that is doesn't necessarily correspond to the code that was originally written.  The compiler could have transmuted your original source code into something else.

Comment: What was the code before? What is the problem with the compiler generated code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774570/how-winrt-events-are-interoperate-with-net) that's something new coming along with the Windows Runtime. Maybe your decompiler isn't able to cope with that.

Regarding the information linked above your code should translate into:

```
private void Start_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  dispatcherTimer.Tick += timer_Tick;
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replace. Worked perfectly!!!

Answer (score 3):

That line almost certainly translates back to:

```
this.dispatcherTimer.Tick += timer_Tick;
```

and I say that because it's adding an event handler `AddEventHandler` and referencing `dispatcherTimer.add_Tick` and `dispatcherTimer.remove_Tick`, which would almost certainly be the add and remove handlers for the `Tick` event.

Comment: This code throws an error with no extension method. But this code **dispatcherTimer.Tick += timer_Tick;** worked correctly. Why?

Comment: @Mac, I'm not sure, but I updated it to reflect the correct code. Thanks for the information.